# Retrieving Message-Id using CakeEmail on Amazon SES via SMTP

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services, cakephp-2.3, amazon-ses

I'm using CakePHP 2.6 and using CakeEmail to send a verification email to users.

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
                $Email->to($this->request->data['Account']['account_email']);
                $Email->subject('Verify your account before you continue');
                $Email->send('http://localhost/Accounts/verify/'.$this->request->data['Account']['account_verificationhash']);
```

As Amazon SES rewrites the message-id, I cannot attribute complaints and bounces to a specific email message. According to their docs, Amazon SES returns the message ID in the final SMTP response. I.e.`(250 Ok <Message ID>)`

How can I retrieve that response code?

Comment: What do you mean by : _I cannot attribute complaints and bounces to a specific email message_? Specifically what "complaints"? Are you trying to use the response codes to determine if the email was successfully delivered?

Comment: I cannot attribute complaints and bounces to a specific email message? Specifically what "complaints"?

Email feedback complaints, particularly spam complaints.

Are you trying to use the response codes to determine if the email was successfully delivered?

No, I'm trying to pull the message-id out of the response message.

Amazon takes the message-id that CakeEmail generates, and rewrites it. This is for their internal tracking purposes. They return that ID to you in the response message "250 Ok ****message ID****". Then SES uses that message-ID to report any complaints or bounces.

Comment: Does the return value of the send method have the 250 response code - i.e., `$result = $Email->send();`?

Comment: I tried that. It passes an array of the headers and message. The message-id header passed is the message-id before SES rewrites it.

Comment: Did you try working with sns notifications?

Comment: It's possible to use the SNS delivery notification, it also could be messy if multiple messages are sent to the same email address at the same time. It doesn't seem like an elegant way, when the data is already passed in the SMTP dialogue.

Comment: Digging around the code, I don't think you can without creating your own transport. If you look at the [_smptSend](http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/source-class-SmtpTransport.html#205), it never sends back anything to the calling code except the actual code (e.g., 250)

Comment: @AgRizzo 2.1 is a little outdated, in later versions the [**last response**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-SmtpTransport.html#_getLastResponse) is being buffered. However since the message id is probably contained in the response for the `DATA` command, this will still require a custom/extended transport, as publicly the last response is the response to the `QUIT` command. It's a little more comfortable in 3.x where you can keep connections alive.

Answer (score 1):

On line 316 of ./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php if you add a third element to the array returned after you send a mail with the standard CakePHP Smtp transport you can force the last response from SES to be returned thereby giving you the ID link to attribute AWS SNS delivery notifications, bounces or complaints.

```
$this->_content = array('headers' => $headers, 'message' => $message, 'response' => $this->_lastResponse);
```

'response' then provides...

```
Array(
    [code] => 250
    [message] => Ok 00000151379549a4-6e36766f-849e-4e3c-9ac9-6ac1c6ad5434-000000
)
```

Suggest you duplicate/mimic the Smtp transport to avoid that hack being overwritten as you update CakePHP (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#creating-custom-transports).

From the e-mail itself:

> Message-ID:
>   <0000015137aa362a-f53a549b-9420-4056-8623-c24ecf8785de-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com>

Grab the actual Message ID with this:

```
$message['Email']['message_id'] = preg_replace('/Ok /', '', $response['response'][0]['message']);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Cake 3.x We can get with this

```
$email = new Email();

// Use a named transport already configured using Email::configTransport()
$email->setTransport('amazonses');

$email->send($html);

debug($email->getTransport()->getLastResponse());

Array(
    [code] => 250
    [message] => Ok 00000151379549a4-6e36766f-849e-4e3c-9ac9-6ac1c6ad5434-000000
)
```